# extracting meta data from binary docs in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am try trying to extract metadata from binary files and set them as properties I executed the following code.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $url := "/documents/test.docx"
return xdmp:document-set-properties(
  $url, 
  for $meta in xdmp:document-filter(fn:doc($the-document))//*:meta
  return element {$meta/@name} {fn:string($meta/@content)}
)
```

But the meta data is getting stored in string format, so i am not able to compare dates, times and numbers. When I removed that `fn:string()` in the last line meta data is getting stored as attribute named 'content'in name tags .I am using node api to communicate with marklogic, so it was getting difficult to search attributes of properties and compare.

Is there any modification can be done to the code so that meta data can be stored in the same datatypes of original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document properties are always stored as XML, and because of that values are always stored as character data (making them string values effectively). You can still create typed indexes on them, provided the values can be cast as-is accordingly. To pull typed values from document properties, you will have to type cast them yourself.

```
xdmp:document-get-properties($url, xs:QName("last-modified")) ! xs:dateTime(.)
```

HTH!